Why do I get webpack errors when I add `@googleapis/docs` to my project?
When I add the following...
import {docs} from "@googleapis/docs";
"@googleapis/docs": "^3.0.2",

I get the following
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in '/Users/jackiegleason/Code/personal/jrg-ui/node_modules/buffer-equal-constant-time'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
        - install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }


I am confused what it is asking me to do. I am using react-scripts so it would be handling the webpack I have no specific config file.

For the Buffer problem specifically, you have a few options:

Downgrade to CRA 4
Eject so you can manage the config yourself
Switch to something else for building your app, since create-react-app (and by extension react-scripts) is soft-deprecated

But none of that will solve all your problems. @googleapis/docs is meant to be used from Node, it's not a client-side library.

I am using it on the client side. The react scripts generates the static files

Also I am unsure how changing libs would help as Vite would have the newer web pack as well. Is the Google docs api generally out of date?

@Jackie it doesn't look like it's out of date. Last publish was three days ago. But I think you're misunderstanding what I said. FIrstly, Vite and Webpack are different build tools. Secondly, googleapis/docs is a server-side library. It's not meant to be used client-side, including in React.

It says in the error message says it has to have a poll fill unless using web pack less than 5 that is why I said out of date and that still seems true.

@Jackie The error message is saying that if you're on Webpack 5.0.0 or higher, you need to manually handle cases when libraries import Node builtins. You presumably are, since you're seeing the error message. The library you're trying to use does not work in the browser. It's a Node library. You'll need to either use the client-side script or manually use the API.
